# Devise change URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

In my application the URLs for sign in, sign up and and sign out were as:

Sign in: `/users/sign_in`

Sign up: `/users/sign_up`

Sign out: `/users/sign_out`

I followed https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes link and changed the URLs as below which is working

Sign in URL should be changed to `/login` instead of `/users/sign_in`

Sign up URL should be changed to `/register` instead of `/users/sign_up`

Sign out URL should be changed to `/logout` instead of `/users/sign_out`

The issue that I am facing is that even if I hit the old URL like `/users/sign_in` I am able to access the sign in screen which should not be the case.

I had also checked for redirecting the URLs like:

```
get "/users/sign_in" => redirect("/login")
```

But it is not working.

Can someone suggest something?

Comment: Done with the things...

Comment: Added   get '/users/sign_in' => redirect('/login')
  get '/users/sign_up' => redirect('/register') at the top of all the routes

Comment: show devise related routes from routes.rb file

Comment: If you have found answer by yourself, post as an answer, instead of comment.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the position of routes and it worked for me.